# Is there a script to collect all hooks and filters provided by a plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, documentation

As a plugin developer who wants to provide better documentations to my customers I'm also including a dev section inside my docs.

This section should contain all provided hooks and filters by my plugin including the filename and line. Also, I want to grab the documentation above each hook to display it as documentation of the hook / filter.

Instead of going through every file, I'm very sure that there's a script out there which already does this kind of work.

At least the script should create a TXT file which contains all that stuff.

If someone knows a script to accomplish this I would be really glad if you can share it with me. If I don't get an useful answer, I'll sit down myself, develop a script like this and publish it to GitHub so everyone can use it!

Comment: I recently posted about the WP Parser
here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/407255/26350 where one can parse core or just a custom plugin. The display of the parsed data might be somewhat involved though.

Comment: The parser is way too complex for me and more WP oriented than custom plugin useful. I've developed my own plugin which uses a shortcode to display the hooks and a python script which collects all data. After testing for a while, I will consider upload it to the WordPress library of plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried using the parser, but it's build for WP docs and is a bit too complex for my needs. So I've invented my own little plugin: HookR.

HookR provides a shortcode where you can pass a path to the uploads folder and a file inside containing all plugins hooks within a JSON format:

```
{
  "created": "1660810923",
  "src": "/Users/anonymous/Sites/development/wp-content/plugins/abc",
  "hooks": [
    {
      "name": "abc_encryptor_encrypt",
      "type": "filter",
      "desc": "This filter filters the value which should be encrypted",
      "since": "1.7.0",
      "attrs": [
        {
          "name": "$value",
          "type": "string",
          "desc": "The value which should be encrypted"
        },
        {
          "name": "$key",
          "type": "string",
          "desc": "The encryptor key"
        }
      ],
      "src": [
        {
          "file": "class-abc-encryptor.php",
          "line": 57
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The result on each page with the included shortcode will look like this:

[image]

The JSON file can be created by a Python script. If I get enough upvotes and comments, I may consider publishing the plugin at WP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WordPress [Query Monitor Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/)

It give you access the details of the queries made to the database, CSS, active hooks, and the HTTP API calls by clicking the entries in the dropdown list.

Comment: No, because it don't solves my problem.